# delete flash message injected with ajax Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using js.erb and ajax to inject a flash partial onto a page:

js.erb

```
$('#buttons').before($("<%=escape_javascript(render 'shared/flash', :flash => flash)%>)").fadeIn('<%=Board::FADE_IN%>').delay(<%=Board::FLASH_TIMING%>).fadeOut('<%=Board::FADE_OUT%>', function(){ $('div.flash-blcok').remove(); }))
```

However I noticed that if a user refreshes the page they see the flash message in the layout.

I am using flash.now[:success] in the controller and thought that it would eliminate any flash messages but it does not seem to be working.

How can I delete the flash?

Comment: You can avoid this by not using RJS. It's been removed (extracted, really) in 3.1 because it is bad at separating concerns. Put your JS in .js files and send back JSON.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW In your code snippet you may have had a misspelling.

You had:

```
$('div.flash-blcok').remove()
```

This question helped me get to a solution for my own problem. Thanks for asking it.